# Transferred ownership of smart contract to Gnosis Safe multisig address

Tags: gnosis-safe

Someone transferred ownership of a smart contract (using transferOwnership function) to my Gnosis Safe address. On Etherscan, the contract shows as the owner being the Gnosis Safe address, which indicates it has worked.

Is there any issue in having a smart contract owner being a Gnosis Safe address? There would be no barriers here in terms of editing the contract, correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue with that (as long as there is no special handling the the contract that you have ownership of).

OpenZepplin has a blog post for this use case: https://blog.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-app-for-gnosis-safe/